# How to ger Url parameters with Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-charts

How can I get a parameter from the url? For example, if have:

```
page1.html#token=12345
```

and I need to get the `token` from the url, how can I do that in sencha?

Answer (score 2):

www.test.com/?drink=beer

```
var params = Ext.urlDecode(location.search.substring(1));
//substring(1) removes the question mark

console.log(params);
//Get the value of a key by using:
console.log(params.drink);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use Sencha's built-in routing functionality and pass your parameters as individual URI segments, i.e. www.webapp.com/user/param1/param2. This makes for cleaner URIs and you can use Sencha's map.connect() to setup the routes.

Comment: Can you link to an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Ext.urlDecode("token=12345"); // returns {token: "12345"}